# cannot type any text in search select2 using modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select, jquery-select2

When I try to search the dropdown list from Select2, I can't type any text inside it.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="mb-3 custom-select2" id="branch_field">
   <label class="form-label" style="color: #8B8B8B; font-size: 12px;">Cabang / POS</label>
   <select class="form-select disabled required" data-width="100%" id="branch" name="branch" style="font-size: 14px;">
      <option></option>
      <?php
         if (count($branch) > 0) {
            foreach ($branch as $val) {
                echo '<option value="' . $val->BranchID . '">' . $val->BranchFullName . '</option>';
            }
         }
         ?>
   </select>
   <div class='notif_info'><span class="text-danger"><i class="material-icons fs-6 m-1 text-danger">warning</i>Cabang / POS tidak boleh kosong</span></div>
</div>
```

I tried put dropdownParent but still didn't work:

```
$('#branch').select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#mappingModal"), 
    placeholder: "Pilih Cabang / POS"
});
```

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of your code ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Maybe disabled class or another javascript is preventing you from typing.